# how to combine objects with different modifiers in a blender, with the ability to further edit each of the modifiers

Tags: blender

Let's say there is a tree. Its crown has a Subdivision Surface modifier applied. The crown must be combined with the trunk (namely, through ctrl j). The barrel has no modifiers. How to combine them into one object (because then you need to manipulate the entire tree), but at the same time retain the ability to apply different modifiers to these two parts, as well as edit existing ones after merging (Subdivision Surface in this case)? Somewhere they wrote to apply the Apply modifier and then merge. But how then to edit it after application?? And what if I want to combine objects into one, but be able to apply different modifiers to different parts of it?

P.S: I've been doing 3D recently, so the question may be banal, but I still can't find the answer. Plus, in the tutorial video, according to which I make the scene, for some reason this problem is not there. The author merges via ctrl j without applying Apply first, indicating the trunk as the last object (which has no modifiers at all), but the modifier does not fly off the crown. For me, with the same actions, the Subdivision Surface flies off the crown

Answer (score 0):

If you combine two objects with different modifiers, the combined mesh will retain the modifiers of the object you selected last.
But if you want to be able to manipulate all the objects and still have control over the modifiers applied to each section, I'd suggest you parent them. For example, parent the crown to the trunk so you could move one of them and have the other follow. It doesnt make them into one object, but it helps to manipulate the entire tree.